# who pays the work visa fee? employee or employer

Tags: management, job-offer, hiring-process, company-policy, visa

My employer hired an immigration expert for all visa processing process, he asked me to pay the fee.
I want to ask that; 
who will pay the work visa processing fee and how much?

Comment: Was there any prior written agreement to relocation or sponsorship costs?

Comment: Can you add some more context? I'm assuming this is a _new_ employer? Are they asking you to organize your own visa? Or are they asking you to pay _them_ so they can organize a visa?

Comment: Depends on the country (and maybe the type of visa). For an H1B in the USA, the employer is required to pay most (if not all) of the visa costs.

Comment: Iftikhar, I believe this question could be reopened, but we really need to know where the company is located first.

Answer (score 11):

Many employers will say that it is your problem to get all the paperwork done that is needed so they are legally allowed to employ you.

However, if you are offered a job, and the company asks you to pay *them* money to get a visa, then it's 99.9% sure that this is fraud, and when you pay there will be another fee, and another one, and what will *not* appear at the end of that tunnel is a job or a visa, because the job never existed.

Iron rule: If a company asks you to pay money to work for them, no matter what the excuse is, then it is fraudulent.